# How to reuse an existing sys.ps1 formatter in an IPython prompt?

Tags: python, terminal, ipython

I have a function `f` that produces a PS1 prompt for python, set as such:

```
sys.ps1 = f
```

Following the instructions in [the documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html), I ended up with the following:

```
from IPython.terminal.prompts import Prompts, Token
from IPython import get_ipython
class MyPrompt(Prompts):
 def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):
     return [(Token, f())]
ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.prompts = MyPrompt(ipython)
```

However, this doesn't work, since `f` returns a string with color codes, which `python` prints directly to the terminal, leading to a colorful prompt, while `ipython` prints escaped, leading to a bunch of escape codes.

I know I can reconfigure `f` to use ipython's internal coloring scheme, but is there a way to force it to use the shell's color codes without escaping them?

While `f` is a function that takes into account information about its environment, here's an implementation that shows its output in one situation (it uses colorama behind the hood, so this is just the ouptut on unix systems).

```
def f():
    return '\x01\x1b[1m\x1b[33m\x02kavi\x01\x1b[0m\x02 \x01\x1b[38;5;214m\x02/home\x01\x1b[38;5;82m\x02/kavi\x01\x1b[38;5;28m\x02\x01\x1b[0m\x02 \x01\x1b[38;5;38m\x02master\x01\x1b[0m\x02 $ '
```

Comment: can you please provide your `f` string?

Comment: @AsavPatel it's dynamically calculated, based on the present working directory and git status

Comment: still any example would help. since I don't have a way to reproduce it on my machine.

Comment: @AsavPatel I added a possible example above

Comment: prompt-toolkit v2 has [ANSI text format](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/examples/prompts/colored-prompt.py#L62-L71) support, but IPython is built on prompt-toolkit v1, it is much easier to rewrite your PS1.

Comment: @georgexsh write that up as an answer and I'll award the bounty. I was hoping there was a clean way, but it looks like there isn't

Comment: What GUI context is IPython running in? Is it a Jupyter notebook, a UNIX terminal, or something else?

Comment: A unix terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPython shell is built on prompt-toolkit, [its style](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.15/pages/building_prompts.html#coloring-the-prompt-itself) could be overridden with `TerminalInteractiveShell._style`:

```
from prompt_toolkit.styles import style_from_dict
from IPython.terminal.prompts import Prompts, Token
from IPython import get_ipython


style = style_from_dict({
    Token.User: '#f8ea6c',
    Token.Path_1: '#f08d24',
    Token.Path_2: '#67f72f',
    Token.Git_branch: '#1cafce',
    Token.Pound: '#000',
})


class MyPrompt(Prompts):
    def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):
        return [
            (Token.User, 'kavi '),
            (Token.Path_1, '/home'),
            (Token.Path_2, '/kavi'),
            (Token.Git_branch, ' master '),
            (Token.Dollar, '$ '),
        ]


ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.prompts = MyPrompt(ipython)
ipython._style = style
```

run it with `ipython -i colored_ipy_prompt.py`:

[image]

Comment: This presumes that the OP is running the ipython shell in a terminal.

Comment: And where is `f()` used in this? The OP wanted to use the output of an existing function, not define new tokens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair point, as OP is importing from `IPython.terminal.prompts`, I assume it is running in a terminal. I have stated that reuse existing ps1 string is hard in a comment, and OP seems just want a colored IPy prompt.